# Error :{"code":"InvalidUri","message":"The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server - Azure Batch Rest API

Tags: azure, api

I am trying to invoke Azure Batch Rest API to create a pool from ADF.

Below is the Post url I am trying -

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/a01c19ca-c50f-4be0-904d-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/
sumo-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts/sumobatch/pools/testpool?api-version=2021-01-01

`testpool` above doesn't exist but something that should be created once the `RestAPi` runs successfully.

However, I am getting the following error code -

Error details

```
Error code 2108
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type
User configuration issue
```

Details

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidUri","message":"The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.\nRequestId:b512af12-c1b7-474a-9773-dcf034b07e0e\nTime:2021-07-18T05:57:31.4199546Z","target":"BatchAccount","details":[{"code":"UriPath","message":"/subscriptions/a01c19ca-c50f-4be0-904d-************/resourceGroups/
sumo-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts/sumobatch/pools/testpool"}]}}
Source Pipeline poolstart
```

Any leads will be highly appreciated ?

Comment: I believe there’s a space before your resource group name and that may be causing the problem. Can you please check that.

Comment: I cross verified. There isn;t a space.   Here is the input request -Input
{
    "url": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/a01c19ca-c50f-4be0-904d-4a91317bde74/resourceGroups/sumo-dev-rg/providers/Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts/sumobatch/pools/testpool?api-version=2021-01-01",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {},
    "body": {},
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": "https://management.core.windows.net/"
    }
}

Comment: Thanks all. This is resolved now. It was a mistake from my end. I didnt place the PUT request before the url.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Poon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16472763/poon). Posting your comment as Answer to help other community members.

> Adding the `PUT` before the `URL` fixed the issue